# How to wait for a Task to complete in a WCF service operation

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I apologize if a variation of this question has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find an answer that applies to my current situation.

I am working on a project where I've been asked to expose the operations of a Task based provider via a WCF service. The provider interface explicitly defines `Task<T>` as the return type of each method, here's an example:

```
public interface IContactProvider
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAllContacts(); 
}
```

In an attempt to expose this as a WCF service, I've basically defined a "synchronous" version of the provider interface to use as a service contract resulting in a service implementation that looks like this:

```
public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    private IContactProvider contactProvider;

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContacts()
    {
        return contactProvider.GetAllContacts().Result;
    }
}
```

My instinct tells me that I'm doing something wrong here and that I should be "waiting" for the `Result` to be available some other way. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing should work fine (`Result` will block until the task completes), but are you using .NET 4.5? If so you could simply declare your service operation contract to return the `async Task<T>` directly. That way your clients would automatically get the option to call it synchronously or asynchronously (via the generated service client).

Here's a post I found more useful than the MSDN docs: http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2012/01/21/what-is-new-in-wcf-in-net-4-5-taskt-and-async.aspx

Comment: I guess the fact that `Result` blocks is what I was worried about. I don't want to create a scenario where the service deadlocks but maybe that's not possible here? Also, I am using .NET 4.5, but I can't guarantee that other clients will be .NET (or .NET 4.5 for that matter); would using Task<T> in the service contract cause problems for those clients?

Comment: @sellmeadog You should not re-use the same interface for the client and server side contracts. The server side interface can be `Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAllContactsAsync();` and the client side interface can be `IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContacts()` and it will "just work" with WCF. WCF automatically exposes a sync and async version of every method to the client but the server only needs to implement one of the two.